# get neighbors function in R

Tags: r, image-processing, machine-learning, image-segmentation

I have a data that is actually an image in form of 256 x 256 matrix. I want to write a function call it "get.nbhd" that selects 4 neighbors for a pixel and stores it as a vector. Then call that function whenever needed. If the pixel is corner or on the border there will be 2 and 3 neighbors respectively. Here is a toy data set. So for any pixel in the middle say d[i,j] the 4 neighbors will be {d[i-1,j],d[i+1,j],d[i,j+1],d[i,j-1]}. For the 4 corner pixels the 2-neighbors will be {d[i,j-1],[i+1,j]} ,{d[i,j+1],d[i+1,j]}, {d[i-1,j],d[i,j-1]}, {d[i-1,j],d[i,j+1]}. The top and bottom border pixels will have 3 -neighbors as {d[i-1,j],[i+1,j],d[i,j-1]}. Any help is appreciated.

```
    > x<- matrix(rbinom(8*8,1,0.5),8,8)
    > x
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
    [1,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0
    [2,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    1
    [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
    [4,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1
    [5,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    0
    [6,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
    [7,]    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0
    [8,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function gives you the neighbours of `m[i, j]` in a vector:

```
get.nbhd <- function(m, i, j) {
  # get indices
  idx <- matrix(c(i-1, i+1, i, i, j, j, j+1, j-1), ncol = 2)
  # set out of bound indices to 0
  idx[idx[, 1] > nrow(m), 1] <- 0
  idx[idx[, 2] > ncol(m), 2] <- 0
  return (x[idx])
}
```

The function profits from the fact using zero as an index will not give an error, but just return no value. Therefore, indices that are too large are set to zero.

As an example, I use a different matrix than you did, because it is not easy to check the correctness of the results, if there are only ones and zeroes.

```
x<- matrix(1:25,5,5)
x
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
## [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
## [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
## [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
## [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
get.nbhd(x, 2, 3)
## [1] 11 13 17  7
get.nbhd(x, 1, 5)
## [1] 22 16
get.nbhd(x, 5, 3)
## [1] 14 20 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! This helps a lot. One more question. How can I modify this function to extract indices of neighbors instead of actual values. When I started coding I realized I also need another function that returns the indices of neighborhood. For example for point d[1,1] the function gives d[1,2] and d[2,1] as neighbor indices. If its not appropriate then I can post it as another question.

Comment: The indices are calculated on the first line of the function. From this, you need to remove the rows with invalid indices. (In the function, I only set invalid indices to zero, but you'll probably want to remove them completely.) If this is not enough to help you, I think it would be better to ask a  new question. Don't forget to look for helpful answers on SO and with Google first!

Comment: Thanks. I was able to modify your function by removing the rows with zero !